# Consulta beneficio pedidos de compra/venta

Tags: sql-server, join

Estoy intentado hacer una consulta que dadas 4 tablas,
Cabecera de pedidos de compra,detalle de pedidos de compra,
Cabecera de pedidos de venta,detalle de pedidos de venta.
Me retorne una relación:

```
         DocCompra  docVenta  TotalCompraLin    TotalVenta
         3-SF1         SF1      79.000000       118.580000
         5-SF2         SF2      424.600000      448.890000
```

El problema es que tal y como lo estoy haciendo:

```
select cabcom.NUMERO +'-'+cabcom.relVenta as DocCompra,cabven.letra + cabven.NUMERO docVenta,
SUM(detcom.IMPORTE) as TotalCompra, 
SUM(detven.IMPORTE) as TotalVenta
    FROM c_pedico as cabcom
    INNER JOIN c_pedive as cabven
        ON LTRIM(RTRIM(cabcom.relVenta)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(cabven.LETRA))+LTRIM(RTRIM(cabven.NUMERO))
    INNER JOIN d_pedico as detcom
        ON cabcom.EMPRESA = detcom.EMPRESA AND cabcom.NUMERO = detcom.NUMERO AND cabcom.PROVEEDOR = detcom.PROVEEDOR 
    INNER JOIN d_pedive as detven
        ON  cabven.EMPRESA = detven.EMPRESA AND cabven.LETRA = detven.LETRA AND cabven.NUMERO = detven.NUMERO
GROUP BY cabcom.NUMERO,cabcom.relVenta,cabven.LETRA,cabven.numero
```

el primer registro es valido, eso se debe a que el detalle del documento 3-SF1 solo tiene una línea, pero en el segundo (5-SF2), que tiene dos , me hace el acumulado de las líneas por duplicado, ya que si vemos por ejemplo el contenido del detalle del pedido compra 5-SF2:

```
DocCompra   articulo      importe
5-SF2      PHILIPS243      107.800000
5-SF2      HYPERXAO01      104.500000
```

Lo mismo me hace con los pedidos de venta, es evidente que estoy construyendo mal la consulta,
¿me podéis hechar un cable por favor?

Comment: ¿Existe una relación entre el articulo comprado y el vendido? Si existe, no se ve que lo estés indicando en la consulta que haces.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, ambos pedidos, tanto el de compra como el de venta, serán siempre iguales, lo único que variará será el importe de la línea.

Comment: Ok, entonces lo que te está faltando es la relación entre cada línea. o al menos yo no la veo. Algo como esto `NNER JOIN d_pedive as detven  ON  cabven.EMPRESA = detven.EMPRESA AND cabven.LETRA = detven.LETRA AND cabven.NUMERO = detven.NUMERO AND detven.ARTICULO = detcom.ARTICULO`

Comment: Hola de nuevo, la relación ya está hecha, no necesito relacionar los artículos entre documentos, solo sumar el total de la lineas de cada uno de los documentos y comparar para extraer los beneficios. Es raro, pero se me exige así.
De hecho la consulta que adjunté en la pregunta hace lo que necesito, solo que cuando un documento tiene mas de una línea como es el importe se suma n veces.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer y podría darte una respuesta de como hacerlo, pero si existe la relación entre los dos detalles, simplemente agregala como  te lo indique más arriba, ahora lo que tienes es un producto cartesiano 2 filas de ventas x 2 fila de compras terminas con 4 filas que aplican a las sumatorias, por eso las sumatorias se duplican.

Comment: Gracias mil @PatricioMoracho, he hecho lo que me dices, obtengo el mismo resultado. Aparte, se me ocurre que el cliente puede entrar una linea con cargo (siempre en ambos documentos) que no esté asociado a ningún artículo informado en el sistema. Por eso te decía lo de hacer solo el sumatorio de las líneas sin tener en cuenta los artículos.

Comment: Añadiendo el filtro `Where detven.ARTICULO = detcom.ARTICULO` funciona bien, que al fin y al cabo es lo que me decías tú. Sin embargo, tengo el problema que te mencionaba anteriormente, los artículos, pueden no tener un código como tal a pesar de tener un precio, en cuyo caso, el filtro no me sirve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que está ocurriendo es un producto cartesiano entre los detalles de ventas y los de compras al no tener una relación de fila a fila, lo que termina produciendo una duplicación en la suma. Si existiera una relación entre cada linea del detalle de los pedidos de ventas con los de compra, faltaría indicarla. Sino lo que se debería hacer es sumar independientemente los dos pedidos si incorporar los detalles en la relación:

```
SELECT  cabcom.NUMERO,
        SUM(detcom.IMPORTE)  as TotalCompra,
        V.TotalVenta
        FROM c_pedico as cabcom
        INNER JOIN d_pedico as detcom
              ON cabcom.EMPRESA = detcom.EMPRESA 
              AND cabcom.NUMERO = detcom.NUMERO 
              AND cabcom.PROVEEDOR = detcom.PROVEEDOR
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(cabven.LETRA))+LTRIM(RTRIM(cabven.NUMERO)) as relVenta,
                        SUM(detven.IMPORTE) as TotalVenta
                        FROM c_pedive as cabven
                        INNER JOIN d_pedive as detven
                              ON  cabven.EMPRESA = detven.EMPRESA 
                              AND cabven.LETRA = detven.LETRA 
                              AND cabven.NUMERO = detven.NUMERO
                        GROUP BY LTRIM(RTRIM(cabven.LETRA))+LTRIM(RTRIM(cabven.NUMERO))
               ) as V
               ON V.relVenta = LTRIM(RTRIM(cabcom.relVenta))
        GROUP BY cabcom.NUMERO,
                 V.TotalVenta
```

Lo que hacemos es calcular la suma del pedido de ventas en una subconsulta, y lo relacionamos con el pedido de compras, al estar ya sumarizado el detalle, no tenemos el problema original. La relación por `left` o por `inner` dependerá de lo que se quiera: ver los datos del pedido de compras y si tiene los de ventas o ver únicamente los casos dónde hay un pedido de compra y uno de venta.

Comment: Es exactamente eso lo que necesito, muy amable.